# How can I detect which file maps this key in vim?

Tags: vim

Using vim, I found that some key is mapped to something I didn't do that.

When press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, vim does strange movement.

shown after checking with `:imap<CR>`

```
i <Tab>      * pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "\<TAB>"
i <Tab><Tab>   <ESC>o
```

I want to remove that things.

But I have no idea about where these are from.

How can I detect exact file which mapped these?

I use Listmaps, but in the result, there is no map about this.

and also tried grep like:

```
$grep -r 'map <Tab>' ~/.vim
```

only got no results.

Sorry for short English, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:verbose` command:

```
 :verbose imap <tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mappings are saved locally to each file, which you used, when entering these maps. You could try using `:unmap` (`:[nixo]unmap`) to delete these mappings, which often times didn't work for me.

What works is *deleting* your vim `views` files, which store this option and many more associated to specific files. Delete all to completely get rid of your old mapping! (Backup, just in case)

Default directories are

```
$VIM/vimfiles/view (windows)
~/.vim/view (unix)
```

See :h viewdir for the complete help.